# thinking in D3 - select vs append

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can someone explain like i'm 5 how this D3 syntax actually works?

```
var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'link');
```

What it seems to do is just append links to the tree.

But how I read that is "select everything that is of class link, and append an attribute class=link". How it can select before those exist is puzzling.

Why is there a "select" before the items actually exist?
Does select really mean "insert"?

Comment: This link has step by step explanation - https://www.dashingd3js.com/binding-data-to-dom-elements

Comment: thanks. that does explain it and answers the obvious question that the API is counter intuitive, since it asks "but wait, what?" a few times. neanderthal.

Comment: You don't even need the last line `.attr("class", ".link")` for this to work. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/2135/selections/16948/the-role-of-placeholders-in-enter-selections#t=201608310519416966291

Comment: This seems to explain it. WAT? Is right. Even the author knew it was confusing as he wrote it...   https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

Comment: It's confusing at first, but once you understand the core concept, the syntax becomes more intuitive. The `selectAll('.link')` generalizes your use cases for binding data to elements. 1. There are no elements, therefore add all of the data. 2. There are some existing elements, but less than the size of data, so update the existing, and enter the new. 3. There are more existing elements than the size of data, so update the existing, and remove the rest. It's basically a one liner CRUD operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line by line analysis would like below:

Select all the DOMs having class `link`.

```
var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
```

To all those links bind the data. Here data links is an array.
    `links[0]` is bound to first DOM if present.
    `links[1]` is bound to second DOM if present.
    ..so on

```
.data(links)
.enter()
```

**Case 1:**
If the array links has 2 elements and the selection DOM elements has 0 elements. 
Then 2 line DOM will be appended to the svg DOM.

**Case 2:**
If the array links has 2 elements and the selection DOM elements has 1 element. 
Then 1 new line DOM will be appended to the svg DOM.

**Case 3:**
If the array links has 2 elements and the selection DOM elements has 2 or more elements. 
Then 0 new line DOM will be appended to the svg DOM.

```
    .append('line')
    .attr('class', 'link');
```

This would be a good [read](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data)

Comment: I don't think this answer makes sense. To all those links... the point is there are no links at the start of that expression. The links get created *after* the select in the "append".

Comment: Yes correct! earlier there was no link so `svg.selectAll('.link')` will give an empty selection. That's my Case1. In that empty selection you will add new links based on the data you have passed.

Comment: actually I just read a bostock piece about joins. It doesn't give an empty selection, it sets up an "enter()" with newly created nodes. Very bizarre API but reading backwards and squinting I can see what it's doing. Just wish it was more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it is totally confusing to have to make a selection before it even exists. BUT by calling `data(someDataArray)` on the selection, this placeholder selection is now bound to your data.

Now, for everything that will `enter` the `data` in `someDataArray`, d3 will `append` a corresponding SVG `line` (and attach the relevant data).

If `someDataArray` changes, d3 can change the appearance of the attached SVG node with `update` or even remove the old node that no longer has associated data with `exit`.